# why there is huge difference between execution time of two below queries?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, where-clause, sql-like

First query (which takes almost 14 seconds to return rows)

```
select * from table_1 
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.column= table_2.column0
where table_2.column2 LIKE "%string%";'
```

Explain result:

[image]

table_1 has 300k records and table_2 has 330k records.

Second query (which returns rows in almost 2.5 seconds)

```
select * from table_1 
where table_1.column1 LIKE "%string%";
```

Explain result:

[image]

How can I make my first query faster?

Comment: First is INNER JOIN of two tables. And There is only one table in Second one. So obviously it will be faster than the first one.

Comment: I understand that join leads to process more no. of rows, but here we are scanning nearly equal no. of rows in each query as I can see EXPLAIN result of both queries (have updated the question with results of EXPLAIN command) . If u have noticed in first query LIKE operation is done on column from other table(not on the base table) is this can be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

1) When joining two tables, it is obvious that it should process more rows. So, query 2 is slower than query 1.

2) I assume that you know indexes will be faster.

Joining is on table_1.column= table_2.column0.

If both or any one among table_1.column and table_2.column0 are non indexed columns, your query should go to the table and search instead of using index to make the join. Index querying will be faster. Consider if you can add index on these two columns.

3) In both the queries, you are using 'LIKE "%string%"'. Please consider again if you need to use %string%. No index will be used if there is a '%' in the starting of the string. Hence this will not be an index scan.

And don't add index to all the columns. This will make insert, update and delete operations slower. Too much indexing is not recommended. Choose the columns to index based on the frequency in which you use a column.

Use EXPLAIN command to check how your query is being executed.

Comment: can you please post explain result for both the queries ?

Comment: I understand that join leads to process more no. of rows, but here we are scanning nearly equal no. of rows in each query as I can see EXPLAIN result of both queries (have updated the question with results of EXPLAIN command) . Also "column" and "column0" are indexed where as "column1" & "column2" is not indexed and LIKE clause is used in these non-indexed columns only. If u have noticed in first query LIKE is operation is done on column from other table(not on the base table) is this can be the reason ?

Comment: @farhan 
Such a coincidence we both work in same company :)
In your first query, estimated number of rows is 319355. 
In your second query, the number of rows is not 319355. For every row in CampaignOrgDetails, 1 row is read from the CmpGroupMappings table. The estimated number of row reads in CampaignOrgDetails is 319355. So, for every row in that 319355, one row is read from CmpGroupMappings.

And that too if the column is a text column, data will be stored in disk instead of memory. So, searching for a text in text column may take more time than a normal varchar column.